# Static Public IPs / Multiple Subnets

Tags: networking

I need some help with our network setup. Here are some facts before I ask questions: -

1. My ISP provided a static public IP (and a subnet mask) that I set as WAN-facing on my router.
2. The router uses DHCP to NAT to several LAN devices. All devices are able to access internet without problems.
3. All LAN devices are on same LAN subnet.
4. We have leased 5 additional public static IPs for use with our 5 servers. These servers are required to be publicly accessible without having to go through VPN.
5. These static public IPs are on a subnet that is different (again, different) from subnet in fact# 1 above.
6. ISP refuses to provide static IPs that are on same subnet as in fact#1.
7. My router supports VLAN.

Now the questions: -

1. How should I configure my router to accommodate the 5 public servers? I know every router is different but a simple 1-2-3 in English will be helpful.
2. I have 5 public IPs but what should be the subnet mask and gateway to be set on each of the 5 servers?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: The answer to this question hinges upon the type of router you have. Some routers (mainly SOHO routers) are not even capable of doing this (at least not without flashing the firmware to something else).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. What should I look for in my router to determine if it is capable of doing this?

Comment: most SOHO routers don't let you specify more than one WAN IP in the default firmware. You need to have a more configurable OS on the router (like routeros, ios, ddwrt, tomato, etc). How you do it after that depends on the OS and the IPs/masks that were given to you. The general config I was thinking of is that you have your router WAN IP setup on the WAN port and then you have routes for the other blocks set up through your WAN. You'd statically assign those IPs on LAN interfaces and plug what you want into those ports.

Comment: My Netgear router (running default OS) has 4 WAN ports that can be configured independent of each other(for fail over). However, I have only one "incoming" ethernet hand-off from ISP. So I can use only one out of 4 WAN ports.

Comment: Hmm, what model of netgear is this? something like an srx5308?

Comment: Correct, NetGear ProSafe SRX5308.

Comment: Those are somewhat unique solutions that don't fit into the typical model. So that does have 4 WAN ports, and each have there own specific configuration page in the GUI where you can specify individual WAN IPs, subnet mask, gateway and DNS servers. In this particular case, you would enter each into each port. Looks like you're limited to 4 IPs though (it doesn't seem to be able to do routed blocks, so even if you could get a solid block of public IPs, not sure this could do it). The ports are 1:1 WAN to LAN, so just plug the servers into the corresponding LAN port for each configured WAN port.

Comment: Look at the bottom of page 33: http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/SRX5308/SRX5308_RM_23July2012.pdf

Comment: Thank you. We have a block of 25 public IPs (including future expansion) so unfortunately our current Netgear will not suffice. Let me see if I can get the boss to spend some money and buy another router.

Answer (score 0):

SRX5308 Netgear can work well in that scenario. What you need to do is configure the normal LAN IP's (Private) on one of the interface and then the public subnet on the other. Then configure the LAN Homing by adding that or those specific Public IPs in use on your network.